# FacebookOAthClient is not exist in facebook c# SDK v6.0.20

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

I have facebook c# sdk v 6.0.20 installed.

```
`Facebook.FacebookOAthClient cc = new Facebook.FacebookOAthClient();`
```

But when i try to create an object of type FacebookOAthClient it shows an error

> The Type or namespace name 'FacebookOAthClient' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'Facebook' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

So please help me.Is there any other way to exchange the access token with code?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a 'u' : FacebookOAuthClient cc = new FacebookOAuthClient();